# python split string according to letter position in another string

Tags: python

Ok so lets say I have two strings.

the first string is a series of 44 o's with 6 random v's

the second string is a some text and is 44 characters in length

```
random_string = "bzpsvawxqpvjmldhnmvdseftystvfjimcrwoftvchmqlvwugcm"
some_text = "LoremIpsumDolourSitAmettyConssecteturAdipisc"
```

I am looking for a way to split the some_text string based on the v split of random_string.

```
random_string = "oooovooooovooooooovoooooooovoooooooooovooooovooooo"
splitted_string = random_string.split('v') 
print(splitted_string)
#['oooo', 'ooooo', 'ooooooo', 'oooooooo', 'oooooooooo', 'ooooo', 'ooooo']
```

but i would like to apply this split pattern to some_text to achieve

```
['Lore', 'mIpsu', 'mDolour', 'SitAmett', 'yConssecte', 'turAd', 'ipisc']
```

Comment: So you want to take string slices which have a length that is equal to the length of the "o" strings. Have you tried to do just that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use string slices, based on lengths of the split `random_string` parts

```
text_split = []
current_i = 0
for random_substr in random_string.split('v'):
    text_substr = some_text[current_i:current_i+len(random_substr)]
    text_split.append(text_substr)
    current_i += len(random_substr)
print(text_split)
```

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution, I hope it is general enough for you:

```
import re

random_string = "oooovooooovooooooovoooooooovoooooooooovooooovooooo"
some_text = "LoremIpsumDolourSitAmettyConssecteturAdipisc"

b = [m.start() for m in re.finditer('v', random_string)]
b = [0] + b + [len(b)]

c = [ some_text[b[j]:b[j+1]] for j in range(len(b)-1)]
print(c)
```